# What is the best way to replicate data between 30 branches and center?

Tags: networking, replication, multisite

I have 30 branches I want to connect them to a center site to backup important data daily, what is the best method to do that with cost efficient way and without adding to much operation overhead?
What software and hardware you would use? Is wan optimizer is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide details of what you have tried and what issues that present that need to be solved. Otherwise this is just going to be opinions.

Include how much data, how much does it change between updates, what network performance do you have between sites and centre and what form does the data take - file, emails, database etc.

That will hopefully give us enough to answer.

For example - wan optimisation, that depends on budget and change ability of the data.